# What's this tense called: "I been done ate"?

Tags: american-english, dialects

Growing up in a Black family in the US, I frequently heard people have conversations like this:

Mom: Have you eaten yet?
Kid: Yeah, Mom, I *been* done ate.

Wife: Have you fixed the sink yet?
Husband: Woman, I *been* done fixed it.

(Emphasis is on the word "been")

The meaning has always been the same: not only have I done it, I did it some time ago. This led me to believe that it might be an actual tense in use in more than one language, and in more than one dialect of English.

Am I right about that? What is the tense called? Are there other such tenses in use in parts of the English-speaking world that I might not have heard of?

---

I forgot to add that I found an article online, called "[Notes on African American English](http://homepages.uwp.edu/canary/aavelang.html)". I disagree with parts of it, but section 5.2.2 seems about right:

> 5.2.2 Also found in AAE (and some other varieties of English) is an
>   uninflected done for a resultant
>   state: I done ate (I've already
>   eaten), I had done ate (I'd already
>   eaten). For some speakers, this can be
>   combined with the uninflected be and
>   been: I been done ate (I finished
>   eating some time ago), I be done ate
>   (I've usually already eaten).

Comment: Would you say "I done ate", "I been ate", and "I been done ate" in different situations?  If so, do they all have different meanings?  I don't see any references to "been done" per se, just "been" and "done" separately.  Cool question, btw.

Comment: @Kosmo: I've never personally said "I done ate" or "I been ate". I was interested to read about those in the referenced article. I don't recall ever hearing them used. I _do_ use "I been done ate", and find it a useful tense - I don't know what it's called, and wonder where else it's in use and whether other languages have the same tense.

Comment: This is interesting. I have lived in Britain my whole life, and never heard anything like this sort of grammar/construction. It would sound like atrocious English to me. Perhaps it is valid in some American dialects however...

Comment: @Noldorin: thanks. Is there a way in British English to express "I finished that some time ago"?

Comment: I just skimmed through [this article](http://www.ncsu.edu/linguistics/docs/pdfs/walt/PDF-Urban_AAE.pdf), which seems to have a lot of interesting info, but doesn't (that I can see) mention the "been done" + verb construction.

Comment: @John Saunders: I think we'd just use the perfect tense: "I have (already) eaten.". Or possibly: "I am done eating." (This implies a more recent action though.) To distinguish between events that are very recent in the past, you might say: "I have just eaten." (I think that's universal.) Interesting to hear of this usage anyway - if I were to guess, it stemmed from a misuage, but has perhaps become acceptable grammar in certain American dialects.

Comment: @Noldorin: right, but what about my second example? Would you just say, "Woman, I fixed it some time ago"? With "some time ago" meaning an indefinite time ago, likely longer than "last week" or other, more definite time spans that might have been used.

Comment: @John Saunders: In Standard English, we have to use adverbs to express all the nuances of tense and aspect of AAVE.  So, yes, "some time ago" is one way to do that.  In other languages, there are even fewer tenses than Standard English, or even no overt tenses; in those cases, they have to use even more adverbs and similar methods to express the meanings of these tenses.

Comment: @Kosmo: thanks. I would personally say, "some time ago" or "ages ago" in public, but find the "phases" to be a useful addition to the language, at least where they are understood.

Comment: @John Saunders: Yeah, that would be quite acceptable. There's no specific verb construct for it I guess - as a matter of interest, I don't believe any other European languages have one either.

Comment: Call me a curmudgeon (go ahead; I'll wait here), but I call this "perfect illiterate".

Comment: @psu: kind of insulting, no?

Comment: @John Saunders: Yes, intentionally so, and not intended as a serious answer.  I think English is capable of expressing the tense implied, as the examples from AAE demonstrate.  On the other hand, I'm generally suspicious of anything novel, especially in speech, so it's possible I'm just being left behind as the language changes.  I just been done complaining about it.

Comment: @psu: it's not new, it's old.

Comment: @John Saunders:  I didn't say it was new, I said it was novel, meaning, in my Humpty-Dumpty view, that it was new to me.  And I must say that I'm learning a great deal about the language I thought I knew by reading all these comments and answers...something of a humbling experience for someone who's a bit of an undeservedly arrogant academic.

Comment: This is a lot like Jamaican Creole. The inclusion of "been" throws me off a little though. "I done ate" would be perfect, if I remember correctly (I did some research on this back in college). With 'been' as well though, I'm not sure. I suppose the suggested notion of signifying time passed makes sense.

Comment: I think it looks typical of pidgin/creole usage, where uncertainty about the "standard" verb tense forms may lead speakers to throw in redundant elements to emphasise the intended tense. Often, in contexts where listeners are unlikely to correct them, and may actually replicate the usage themselves later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English) and [this article by Joan Fickett](http://books.google.com/books?id=ntI2tjjTE2MC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=%22pre-recent+past%22&source=bl&ots=ULe-o6uWwg&sig=YC8XPAng5KO-ywBeXa6WAGeMCIk&hl=en&ei=AAkpTcekL4KglAfX2c2zAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22pre-recent%20past%22&f=false), it makes the distinction between recent past and pre-recent past:

Recent:

> She done work.

Pre-recent:

> I been seen him.

**Edit**: Still trying to figure out the name for the "been done" + verb tense, which is yet another tense/aspect that doesn't exist in Standard English.

Comment: The Wikipedia article also distinguishes between "He been done work", and "He done been work", though my ear would say that the latter is the same as "He done been working", meaning "until recently, he worked over a long period of time." I wouldn't take this to imply "until recently", though.

Comment: @John Saunders: Oh, I totally missed those down there.  I can see that it is something different from "pre-recent" or "recent" now.  (So my answer needs to be fixed! :)

Comment: I think it is called remote perfective aspect - "Indeed African American English frequently distinguishes between an Immediate Perfective (I done go = I have gone) and a Remote Perfective aspect (I been go = I had gone)." [AAE](https://www.uni-due.de/SVE/VARS_AfricanAmericanEnglish.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This seems a lot like where I might say "I have been done eating for quite some time now." Sounds the same tense with just the "have" omitted and the action verb cast to the past tense.

Comment: I don't think "I been done ate" means the same thing as "I have been done eating for quite some time now".  I think it means "I ate quite some time ago."

Comment: sorry, it doesn't mean that. "Done" doesn't mean "finished" in that sense. The construct means that it happened some unspecified but time ago - not recently.

Comment: @John Saunders, Which makes it an example of grammaticalisation. The concrete meaning of *done*, "complete", has turned into a grammatical marker.